# Searching semantic concepts (defined in RDF) in a given text

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I would like to implement the following function in Java, using Apache Jena API.

- input: a RDF file + an arbitrary text
- what to do: parsing the RDF file, analyzing the arbitrary text to *see* if it contains semantic concepts defined in the RDF file.
- output: list of semantic concepts mentioned in the arbitrary text

How can I do that?

I plan to the following.

```
for (int i = 0; i < conceptsFromRDF.size(), i++) {
    if (text.contains(conceptsFromRDF.get(i).getString()) == true)
        returnConcepts.add(conceptsFromRDF.get(i));  
}
```

Are there more efficient way?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Please show examples of your inputs and desired outputs, as well as explanations for why the output is what you want.

Comment: Your little algorithm is only searching for occurrence of some word in the text. It will only give a probability that the text is about some concept. Counting the number of occurrence of each of those word will increase your accuracy... and there is a lot more you can do be more accurate.

Comment: @Ben75 I think it may even be a little more convoluted than that, as there seems to be a lot of hidden magic here. `text` needn't necessarily be a `java.lang.String`, and who knows how a RDF concept (a graph? a node from the graph?) is being converted to a plain string. We're being asked to assess the efficiency (run-time complexity? memory complexity? readability? feasibility?) of an algorithm that is completely hidden within a black box. Semantic concept literally means "not the lexification of this text, but what it means", so ambiguity is everywhere.